# Current Feedback (CFB) operational amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier

Here is my task:

[image]

Comparator with CFB operational amplifier is shown. It is known Vm=2V and w=314rad/s. Draw time diagram of voltages Vp and Vm, where Vp is voltage on positive input and Vm is voltage on negative input. What is amplitude of voltage Vd=Vp-Vm?
Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: We don't just do your homework for you here.

Comment: I know I can't expect for someone to doy homework for me, but I'm not so familiar with CFB opamps (till now I only studied VFB opamps). Do you have maybe some suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Feedback, what is the feedback ? What would happen if there was a VFB opamp in this circuit instead of a CFB amp ? Note that I do not see any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal current feedback op amp equivalent circuit looks like this:

[image]

The non-inverting input is high impedance (infinity in ideal model). The 'x1' buffer asserts the same voltage at the non-inverting input, but with low impedance (zero in ideal model). This means it supplies whatever current is required to maintain the voltage it asserts.

Depending on circuit attached at the non-inverting input, the voltage asserted there will drive an error current \$i_{err}\$. That error current multiplied by the transimpedance of the amp \$Z(s)\$, measured in Volts/Amp, determines the output voltage \$V_O\$.

Using these facts in the problem you've stated, what is your conclusion as to the voltages that appear at the inverting and non-inverting inputs as a function of time?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I assume that, having in mind relations you gave for ideal opamp, I should apply superposition theorem, firstly analyse circuit with ac voltage active (DC source shorted) and then analyse circuit with DC source active (AC source shorted)?

Comment: I think if you look more closely, you'll find that the input voltage does not affect the voltage on the inverting input, at least for an ideal current-feedback op amp (CFA). If you're using an actual CFA, you'll need to know the input impedance of the inverting input, something on the order of 50 ohms.

Comment: So in case of ideal opamp (what is case here) voltage at "-" input equals voltage at "+" input, so it is 1V DC?

Comment: Yes, that's correct for the ideal case. That's because the impedance of the inverting terminal (Z-) is assumed to be zero, or 0V/A, meaning its voltage doesn't change based on the current drawn from (or pushed into) it.